# Pivot Animator under Wine doesn't work - Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: wine, 23.04

I am trying to install Pivot Animator on Ubuntu 23.04 under Wine.
The installer simply launches, lets me hit next, and crashes. I'm using the latest 4.something.something version, and the latest Stable Wine version. Any help?
[image: the place i can get before crash]

and then, i just get a like 0.1 second loading screen before crash... any help?

p.s im not that technical sooooo tell me like im 7

Comment: Your question as written is unclear. Have you successfully run other Windows applications via Wine, or does just this one application fail? While you may find some support here, you might be better served working with the [Wine support community](https://www.winehq.org/help), as this issue as described seems more related to running this particular application under Wine than it does with an issue with the Ubuntu OS.

Comment: Check with `https://www.winehq.org`. Not all Windows programs are available through `wine`. This is not a Ubuntu problem, this is a `wine` problem.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because wine doesn't support all Windows programs. Wine isn't Ubuntu.  See https://winehq.org